# How to change the size of a tab in a text?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change the size of a tab? For example when you have a `<textarea>`, how can you make it so the size of tab gets smaller?
A space is one column, a tab is often 4 as far as my knowledge goes. How could I make a tab to only take up 3 columns of character space?

`Normal tab size:   |    |`

`Wanted tab size:   |   |`

This would help for displaying code more clearly. Also it would keep the (exported) file size smaller (because one <kbd>Tab</kbd> character is smaller than 3 <kbd>Space</kbd> characters).

I have no idea where to start, and haven't found anything on the internet. So every help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the `tab-size` property but it is not widely supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [**tab-size**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size) (MDN Link)

> The tab-size CSS property is used to customize the width of a tab (U+0009) character.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key)

> In CSS, tabs are preserved in an element as shown above if the attribute white-space set to pre. CSS 3 defines tab-size property, which adjusts the number of spaces for the tab character from the default of 8. The latest version of WebKit supports the tab-size property. The Opera web browser supports the -o-tab-size CSS property, the Firefox web browser supports the -moz-tab-size CSS property with the same meaning.

Note: [**Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-tabsize) is *poor* (IE has zero suppport although the property is under consideration for MS Edge).

Comment: Thanks, `tab-size` was exactly what I were looking for. Luckily it's not something that is important to be supported. It's great for people who run a browser that in fact does support it. But doesn't harm the people who run a browser that doesn't support it.